# How do you use the .done or .complete with .toggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out the correct usage of .complete or .done after .toggle in jQuery. 
I want the button's text to change after the toggle animation completes. I'm not sure I'm chaining these correctly. The [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)  does not have examples of how to use these just that they are "options". How do you use these options? Is it not as below?

```
$(document).on("click", "#new-contact-btn", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#new-contact-row").toggle(200).complete(function(){  

      if ( $("#new-contact-row").is(":visible") ) {
        $(this).text("Cancel");
      } else {
        $(this).text("+ Add New Contact");
      }
    });
});
```

The above code does not work, the button text never changes on click.

Comment: Search the doc page for `// Animation complete.` to find a code example.

Comment: I don't know why this question has been downvoted. It states a clear problem, with an attempt, the relevant code, the expected and current behaviour. OK granted, it could be solved by reading the doc more carefully, but I mean what couldn't.

Comment: @JeremyThille `but I mean what couldn't` lots and lots and lots of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toggle()` doesn't return a promise or deferred object, so calling `complete()` on it won't work.

Instead you need to use the second argument of the method call, the `callback`. If you provide a function here it will be executed when the animation completes. Also note that within this function `this` will refer to the row, not the button, so you you'll need to store a reference to the button in a variable. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#new-contact-btn', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#new-contact-row').toggle(200, function() {
    $('#new-contact-btn').text($(this).is(":visible") ? "Cancel" : "+ Add New Contact");
  });
});
```

```css
div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new-contact-row">Contact Row</div>
<button id="new-contact-btn">+ Add New Contact</button>
```

Comment: The text is on the button, we're checking the visibility of the row.

Comment: Ah, ok that's another issue then as `this` will refer to the `row`, not the `button`. I'll update the answer to cover that too.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly. Thanks for the reply. I like the use of ternary operator too, very succinct.